# Multiple results from single table in mysql

Tags: sql, self-join, mysql-5.0

I have a table in my database with columns:

```
Lead_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
user_id INT(11)
lead_status ENUM('active','win','loss')
```

below sample data:

```
Lead_id     user_id     lead_status
   1          45         active
   2          31         win
   3          11         loss
   4          45         win
   5          11         active
   6          45         loss
```

I need to query the table above to get the following output:

```
user_id      total_leads      active     win     loss
   45             3              1        1        1
   31             1              0        1        0
   11             2              1        0        1
```

I intend to graphically represent the data in the output table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to do it looks is tabulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS total_leads,
    SUM(lead_status = 'active') AS active,
    SUM(lead_status = 'win') AS win,
    SUM(lead_status = 'loss') AS loss
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, an elegant and simple solution. Appreciated.